# I have just installed npm and ionic following the instructions on ionic framework website and as soon as i start a new project i get these errors

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, npm

I'm new to Ionic Framework. I have just installed npm and ionic following the instructions on ionic framework website and as soon as i start a new project i get these errors.

**Ionic Info**

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI : 6.12.4

Utility:
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   NodeJS : v15.7.0
   npm    : 7.4.3
   OS     : macOS Big Sur
```

`% ionic start`

? Framework: Angular
? Project name: app
? Starter template: blank

```
✔ Preparing directory ./aps in 887.30μp
✔ Downloading and extracting blank starter in 143.10ms
? Integrate your new app with Capacitor to target native iOS and Android? No

Installing dependencies may take several minutes.

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

        Ionic Appflow, the mobile DevOps solution by Ionic

           Continuously build, deploy, and ship apps 
        Focus on building apps while we automate the rest 

                   https://ion.link/appflow  

  ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
> npm i

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: aps@0.0.1
npm ERR! Found: typescript@4.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/typescript
npm ERR!   peer typescript@">=4.0 <4.2" from @angular/compiler-cli@11.1.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^11.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer typescript@"~4.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /Users/<username>/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/<username>/.npm/_logs/2021-02-04T03_19_54_834Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.
        
        npm i exited with exit code 1.
        
        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more
        information.
```

Comment: Have you tried editing package.json: typescript: 4.0 to 4.2 and then rerun and see what happens

Comment: Check which command you need to run to start with. maybe ionic serve or ionic install ? Because with every npm project, you have two steps, install and start. Also, docs might help as well: https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/cli

Comment: In package.json the  `"typescript": ">=4.0 <4.2"` how should i change it?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. After running `ionic start` I was able to run `npm install --force` from within the project folder and get @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7 to install. I believe this is a compatibility issue on angular's side. I did confirm I was able to serve the project locally. However, I would not consider this a permanent solution due to the possibility of conflicts with @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.1100.7 and the version of typescript you are currently running.